# Unable to update hive table via JDBC

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am unable to do an Update to my hive table via JDBC.  I able to Select, but not Update.

Connecting to the hive database:

```
Connection connection =  
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/db", "", "");
```

My query:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("update db.test set name='yo yo' where id=1");
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:275)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:355)
at com.spnotes.hive.App.main(App.java:63)
```

Again, I am able to Select but not Update via JDBC.  I am however, able to Update my table via the hive shell only.  I believe this is a user permissions issue.  I have seen other problems where an HDFS directory needed to be granted permissions before it could be written to.

I had to invoke my hive shell with my HDFS user as so:

```
sudo -u hdfs hive
```

Can I somehow pass a "hfds" user via JDBC?  It does not look like this is possible.  This is how I'm thinking the exception will not happen anymore.

Here is the "secure way" of passing in a username and password as so:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2:/hiveserver.domain.com:10000/default;user=username;password=password");
```

BUT this is NOT the same thing as passing the user hdfs.  Perhaps it is possible to link the "username" with permissions to update the hive table?

Any help is welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a update statement in a  `executeQuery()`
For security reasons, any update statement will fail when using this method. Change it to `executeUpdate()`

Also, instead of using queries like this, I suggest using **Prepared Statements**, since by using parameters you make it less vulnerable to SQL Injections

Comment: I have tried using methods executeUpdate and execute.  Both give the same stacktrace as described above:  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask.

Comment: I noticed in your `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/db", "", ""` you are not passing a username. Perhaps if you change it to `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/db", "hdfs", ""`

Comment: I tried that already but it did not work.  I think the username needs to be registered somehow....could be through Hue? and that username needs permissions to alter the table.  Still stuck.